# Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header on redirect

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I'm using asp.net core 2.1 and I have a problem on redirect.
My URL is like:

`HTTP://localhost:60695/ShowProduct/2/شال-آبی`

the last parameter is in Persian.
and it throws below error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x0634
```

but when I change the last parameter in English like:

```
HTTP://localhost:60695/ShowProduct/2/scarf-blue
```

it works and everything is OK.
I'm using below codes for redirecting:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(login);
    }        
    //SignIn Codes is hidden
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {                
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    if (permissionService.CheckUserIsInRole(user.UserId, "Admin"))
    {
        return Redirect("/Admin/Dashboard");
    }
    ViewBag.IsSuccess = true;
    return View();
}
```

how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

General speaking, it is caused by the [`Redirect(returnUrl)`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/83cb05d83c3a56d8755016c66c33a2b4b2f99956/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L316-L323).
 This method will return a `RedirectResult(url)` and finally set the [`Response.Headers["Location"]`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/83cb05d83c3a56d8755016c66c33a2b4b2f99956/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/DefaultHttpResponse.cs#L149) as [below](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/83cb05d83c3a56d8755016c66c33a2b4b2f99956/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/RedirectResultExecutor.cs#L62) :

```
Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = returnUrl;
```

But the `Headers` of HTTP doesn't accept **non-ASCII** characters.

There're already some issues([#2678](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2678) , [#4919](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4919)) suggesting to encode the URL by default.
 But there's no such a out-of-box function yet.

**A quick fix to your issue:**

```
var host= "http://localhost:60695";
var path = "/ShowProduct/2/شال-آبی";
path=String.Join(
    "/",
    path.Split("/").Select(s => System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(s))
);
return Redirect(host+path);
```

Answer (score 22):

Another simpler option (works for me):

```
    var uri = new Uri(urlStr);
    return Redirect(uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: upvoted- works and is simple. I'm going to replace Redirect() with a method that calls this code instead. I can't believe this isn't done by default.

Comment: One caveat- I suspect this method will fail if we're using relative paths for the redirect, much like the original post is showing.

Answer (score 2):

The option that worked for us was to use [UriHelper.Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.encode). This method correctly works with relative and absolute URLs and also URLs containing international domain names.

In our case URLs were always absolute and redirect code looked like:

```
if (Uri.TryCreate(redirectUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri))
{
  return Redirect(UriHelper.Encode(uri));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Flurl](https://flurl.dev)

```
var encoded = Flurl.Url.EncodeIllegalCharacters(url);
return base.Redirect(encoded);
```

This works well for absolute and relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply URL encoding to it for storing it on response header:

```
string urlEncodedValue = WebUtility.UrlEncode(value);
```

Vice versa to decode it:

```
string value = WebUtility.UrlDecode(urlEncodedValue);
```